# Wordpress AJAX call response 0

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, git

I'm tryng to set up a panel, this one [image]

The menu on the top calls different ajax functions in order to display a thumb. Clicking on the thumb you can see the details in the last box of the panel.

I have this `php` functions

```
function GetPostPartner(){
$catPartner = "loop_pb_partner";
get_template_part($catPartner);
wp_die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_GetPostPartner', 'GetPostPartner');

function GetPostEnte(){
$catEnte = "loop_pb_ente";
get_template_part($catEnte);
wp_die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_GetPostEnte', 'GetPostEnte');

function GetPostColl(){
$catColl = "loop_pb_coll";
get_template_part($catColl);
wp_die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_GetPostColl', 'GetPostColl');

function GetPostMedia(){
$catMedia = "loop_pb_media";
get_template_part($catMedia);
wp_die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_GetPostMedia', 'GetPostMedia');

function GetPostDetails(){
$pb_details = $_POST['postURL'];
get_template_part($pb_details);
wp_die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_GetPostDetails', 'GetPostDetails');
```

And those are called by these ajax functions

```
$(document).delegate('h4.homus-partners-global-ajax[data-pb-               cat*=pb_partner]', 'click', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var pb_cat = "pb_partner";
var data = {
    'action': 'GetPostPartner',
    catURL : "loop_"+ pb_cat,
};
$.post(ajaxURL, data, function(response) {
    $( 'ul.homus-partners-section-slide' ).html(response);
});

});

$(document).delegate('h4.homus-partners-global-ajax[data-pb-cat*=pb_ente]', 'click', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var pb_cat = "pb_ente";
var data = {
    'action': 'GetPostEnte',
    catURL : "loop_"+ pb_cat,
};
$.post(ajaxURL, data, function(response) {
    $( 'ul.homus-partners-section-slide' ).html(response);
});

});

$(document).delegate('h4.homus-partners-global-ajax[data-pb-cat*=pb_coll]', 'click', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var pb_cat = "pb_coll";
var data = {
    'action': 'GetPostColl',
    catURL : "loop_"+ pb_cat,
};

$.post(ajaxURL, data, function(response) {
    $( 'ul.homus-partners-section-slide' ).html(response);
});

});

$(document).delegate('h4.homus-partners-global-ajax[data-pb-cat*=pb_media]', 'click', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var pb_cat = "pb_media";
var data = {
    'action': 'GetPostMedia',
    catURL : "loop_"+ pb_cat,
};
$.post(ajaxURL, data, function(response) {
    $( 'ul.homus-partners-section-slide' ).html(response);
});

});

$(document).delegate('li.homus-partners-section-single', 'click',                         function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var pb_post_id = $(this).data('post-id');
  var data = {
    'action': 'GetPostDetails',
    postURL : "single_pb_post_details",
    post_id: pb_post_id
  };
  $.post(ajaxURL, data, function(response) {
      $( '.homus-partners-detalis' ).html(response);
      console.log(pb_post_id);
      console.log(data.postURL);
      console.log(response);
  });

});
```

the response that I have is always 0 even if the console of the last ajax call here above return the right postid. You can find the whole project in this repo 
https://github.com/wanbinkimoon/homus-web.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the code

```
function GetPostPartner(){
$catPartner = "loop_pb_partner";
get_template_part($catPartner);
wp_die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_GetPostPartner', 'GetPostPartner');
```

instead of including the file by get_template_part paste the code here and  then try

Comment: or first try to clear the entire page loop_pb_partner.php and write testing in that file and then check you response, whether you are geting testing or not. In this way we can check whether get_template_part works in ajax callback function or not .. else replace the whole file